# How do Implement the Select query in laravel..?

Tags: mysql, laravel

How do I implement this select query in laravel?

```
SELECT `kilometer` FROM `tyres` WHERE `usage`=1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You need to show us some code, SO does not write code for you.

Comment: You can go even with raw query. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Tyres as model then Eloquent is the best bet.

Try to use App/Tyres

```
Tyres::select('kilometer')->where('usage', 1)->order_by('id', 'DESC')->limit('1)->get()
```

Answer (score 4):

Your query will be

```
Tyres::select('kilometer')->where('usage',1)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(1)->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = DB::table('tyres')->select('kilometer')
        ->where('usage',1)->orderBy('id','desc')->first();

dd($data->kilometer);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write like this:

```
$data = DB::select("SELECT kilometer FROM tyres WHERE usage=1 ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are better off with  [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)

To get kilometers from tyres, you need a tyre model if you dont have one already

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tyre extends Model {
   protected $table = 'tyres';
}


Tyre::select('kilometers')->where('usage', 1)->orderByDesc('id')->limit(1)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = Tyre::select('kilometer')->where('usage', 1)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->limit(1)->get();
```